# xt1527 in boot loop with usb debugging disabled

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot, fastboot, motorola

a couple days ago my xt1527 started acting weird. Gapps started to crash out of nowhere. Today, every app that I tried to open crashed 2 seconds after, so I turned my device off to reboot and see what happened. Well, nothing happened. First it was stuck in the motorola animation but then I turned it off and on again, and it got stuck in the motorola logo (before the animation) and I couldn't turn it off at that point cause it rebooted all the time. When the battery died I charged it for a while and then I was able to enter the recovery mod (actually I think it's the fastboot mode and from there you can access the recovery). I really don't know what to do because literally everything requires adb and hence usb debugging as well. I couldn't find anything to do that didn't require that, I have already downloaded the stock firmware in order to flash it with a script that I found in xda but it clearly didn't work (even though I had already used it with a moto g 1st gen that didn't have usb debugging enabled either). **My question is:** is there anything I can do to turn the phone on without enabling usb debugging? If not, is there any way to enable usb debugging without turning the phone on? **Thanks**

Comment: consider this device may be physical damaged because of emmc wear-out / end of write cycles